# Magento routing problems

Tags: php, magento

I am currently blocked since half a day on a routing problem, and I don't find any solution. I have added a tab on my admin menu, and the action of this tab is triggering a 'Front controller reached 100 router match iterations'. 
All the posts here I saw were on other cases, and i did the fix https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix with no changes. 
All caches are cleared, so i provide data if someone is able to help, it will be appreciated.

My architecture is :

```
Booking/etc/adminhtml.xml
Booking/etc/config.xml
Booking/controllers/ContactRequestController.php
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
        <menu>
            <customer>
                <children>
                    <ContactRequest translate="title" module="whatever_booking">
                        <title>Contact Requests</title>
                        <action>Whatever_Booking/ContactRequest</action>
                    </ContactRequest>
                </children>
            </customer>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <customer>
                            <children>
                                <ContactRequest translate="title" module="whatever_booking">
                                    <title>Contact Request Menu</title>
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                    <children>
                                        <example>
                                            <title>Contact Requests</title>
                                        </example>
                                    </children>
                                </ContactRequest>
                            </children>
                        </customer>

                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
    </acl>
</config >
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Whatever_Booking>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Whatever_Booking>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <whatever_booking>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>

                        <Whatever_Booking>Whatever_Booking</Whatever_Booking>
                        <frontName>booking</frontName>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </whatever_booking>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
<config>
```

controller

```
class Whatever_Booking_ContactRequestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction()
    {
        Mage::log('controller',null,'test.log');
        // this log isnt displayed, i got the error before
    }
}
```

Comment: First glance guess is it has to do with your casing. Perhaps generating this exact admin page using this tool and comparing the code will show you the changes you need to make : http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: wow thanks a lot dude, put this as answer and i validate it!

Comment: in my case, just a type Whatever_Booking instead of whatever_booking in the action field. The action MUST start with frontName

Comment: Done deal, thanks! Glad you found the problem area!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First glance guess is it has to do with your casing.

Perhaps generating this exact admin page using this tool and comparing the code will show you the changes you need to make?

http://silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator